conda create -n myenv python=3.12 > conda activate myenv > python --version keeps returning 3.8.2. Not sure what's wrong
I asked a related question previously, but I don't know how to solve this problem. I am working on a cluster so have limited permission (no sudo ect.)
I am trying to use any other python than 3.8.2, since it keeps giving multiprocessing.Semaphore() issues. After creating and removing conda environments, trying to install python with the new environment or after creating it. Conda deactivating multiple times so I am even out of the base env before conda create. Conda init didn't do anything. No matter what I try it always returns 3.8.2, which is in my python='/home/username/bin/python3.8' folder. I removed any lines that reference 3.8.2 from .bashrc and .bash_profile.
Any help would be appreciated to troubleshoot this issue. I am close to deleting the Python3.8.2 and the .bashrc and .bash_profile since I am running out of ideas, but I think that will break other notebooks that rely on it. The only workaround that seems viable is to open the python3.12 using the entire path to the executable in  /home/username/miniconda3. Thank you for any help.

Conda init should add lines to your .bashrc. You need to reload your shell after that or manually source ~/.bashrc. Make sure that your terminal is loading a -l (login) or -i (interactive) session, which means that it loads the profile or RC, respectively. What terminal are you using? Some are problematic (e.g., tmux) in always moving certain paths to the front of the PATH.

What does type python say? It's possible you have an alias like python=python3.8, which would overrule conda.

I realised using ~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/python3.12 opened the correct python, but that none of the packages installed through pip install ... were available in python. I turned to chatGPT which gave the bandaid of a .sh file with the line: alias python='~/miniconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python3.12' and running conda activate myenv && source ~/activate_myenv.sh. It works, but I would like to know how to remedy the actual cause of this issue. python type in the active environment gives python is /usr/bin/python which I guess is the default for the server?

In /usr/bin/python/ there are multiple files that start with "python" but not anything that is "python3.8"
